# 2 different js file in same html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

what i want to achieve is call external .js file from .aspx, the very first thing is i generate a tooltip function in my master page, then i go to my .aspx to call for external .js file, but it doesnt work. in my .aspx, i cant even get the alert from homepage.js, any one can tell me what is my mistake?

**Master Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function ShowTooltip() {
//do something based on what data is passing in
```

}

**Homepage.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://[Servername]/Scripts/Homepage.js"></script>
```

**Homepage.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("Homepage.js");

  var dataMenu = {
    lbl1: "Fruit",
    lbl2: "auto mobile"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not link the .js file from the Master page instead of loading it from a .aspx file?

Comment: src should be url not absolute OS path to file

Comment: @SolomonClosson cant, the reason behind is, my master page javascript it to call array data from .aspx ,different markup have different id and description, some of them may have same id, so i have to stored the function into master page instead of aspx

Comment: @bansi that is just my example, my environment was url, anyway thanks for notified me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you document is ready before your script is called.

```
$(function(){
  alert("Homepage.js");
});

  var dataMenu = {
    lbl1: "Fruit",
    lbl2: "auto mobile"
  }
```

make sure your path to the file is correct , looks like you have OS path in src..give relative path

Comment: bipen, i think for alert() function, it can be outside a function, my point of view for putting alert is to make sure my script is call

Comment: ya it can be outside a function.... but we need to make sure.. document is ready by the time alert is called.... anyways cheers.. happy coding

Comment: actually i still have problem , my datamenu is not pass to my master page javascript, but my alert is called, the datamenu is work if i put under homepage.aspx, but due to requirement i need to put in another js, do u have any idea for this for me?

Comment: ok that means you need to make datamenu as  global..keep it outside the ready function .. and make sure the js file where you are declaring the datamenu var is loaded before  homepage.aspx(page that you are using datamenu in).